# Make a string in whatsapp start from new line while sending a mesage through whatsapp automation

Tags: python, excel, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

Iam trying to automate whatsapp to send messages to my customers whatsapp numbers that are given in an excel. The excel also contains the message. My problem is the message is been sent as a bnch of string even if Iam trying to cut the line and start in a new line. How can i cut the string and make in start from a new line? Here is my code and excel sheet.

```
import pyautogui as pg 
import webbrowser as web
import time
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/AB/Desktop/contacts2.xlsx") #Replace your excel path(>>2)
data_dict = data.to_dict('list')
leads = data_dict['contact'] #Name acc to your Cloum name in excel
messages = data_dict['msg']  #Name acc to your Cloum name in excel
combo = zip(leads,messages)
first = True
for lead,message in combo:
    time.sleep(4) #Increse time if net is slow(>>3)
    web.open("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+lead+"&text="+message)
    if first:
        time.sleep(6) #Increase time if you want to send msgs slowly
        first=False
    width,height = pg.size()
    pg.click(width/2,height/2)
    time.sleep(8)
    pg.press('enter')
    time.sleep(8)
    pg.hotkey('ctrl', 'w')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
string = f"Some message\n in different line but \n this is new line"
for part in string.split('\n'):
    action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
    action.send_keys(part)
    action.key_down(Keys.SHIFT).key_down(Keys.ENTER).key_up(
        Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).perform()
```

you can have action chain like this